# Many edges connect to one vertex

Tags: modeling

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gV5isYLWN896hm93MYAxXKznaBDSPTzd)[image]
I want to ask how to solve a simple problem: if many edges connect to one vertex.
[image] 
It looks bad in object mode. So I wonder how to solve them.
If you know, please tell me. thanks a lot:)

Comment: please share your file so that we can work on the topology: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I have just shared my file in my question. ( I didn't upload to the website that you provide because I failed  to upload) The place that many edges connected to one vertex is in the dinosaur's leg (where connected to the body). Please take a look, thanks a lot!

Comment: it looks like there are too many triangles, plus faces intersecting, try to keep quads, rebuild a bridge between the body and the leg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess too many triangles create some pinching and artefacts. What you could do is delete the joint between the body and the legs, make sure that they have both the same amount of vertices (I had to delete a non essential edge loop to have 11 vertices on each side), then bridge. Now you have quads everywhere and it looks good.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! What you said really helps me:)